# Preciso condicionar para trazer no group by apenas os dados que não possuem uma condição

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT id_grupo, id_analista 
FROM tb_grupo_analista
GROUP BY id_grupo, id_analista;
```

existe uma terceira coluna chamada `tp_controle`, onde preciso condicionar a *query* de cima para me trazer o agrupado somente onde nesse agrupado não existe o `tp_controle = 2`

Comment: não entendi o que quer dizer com "trazer no group by".. pode explicar melhor?
`group by` é usado para agrupamento, ou seja, quando você usa alguma função para juntar/somar/contar..

Answer (score 0):

Quando você utiliza o comando `SELECT`, pode usar a condição `WHERE` para condicionar o que você quer trazer. Tenta assim:

```
select id_grupo,id_analista from tb_grupo_analista where tp_controle != 2 group by id_grupo,id_analista;
```

EDIT:

para agrupar com a condição, de acordo com o comentário aqui na resposta, você pode tentar esse caminho:

```
select id_grupo,id_analista from tb_grupo_analista where tp_controle = 2
union
select id_grupo,id_analista from tb_grupo_analista where tp_controle != 2 group by id_grupo,id_analista;
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso agrupar apenas os que não tenha esse tp_controle =  2 saca?

Comment: entendi. porem, quando numa seleção vc pede pra agrupar, vc não tem opção de agrupar de maneiras diferentes os elementos na coluna que vc escolheu. pensando aqui, acredito que dê pra fazer um SELECT primeiramente sem agrupamento, com tp_controle = 2, e dar um UNION com outro SELECT, com agrupamento, onde tp_controle != 2. vou atualizar a resposta com o comando pra vc testar